# Not able to create generic bounded class objects with interface

Tags: java, generics, interface, bounded-wildcard, bounded-types

I am trying to use bounded types with generics to create generic objects of subclasses (these implement an interface). But I am getting type mismatch errors when initializing objects with the subclasses.

Here is the interface:

```
public interface ScannableEntity {
}
```

Here's the class that implements this interface:

```
public final class Attachment implements ScannableEntity {
 .
 .
 .
}
```

Now I created 2 classes (**SegmentPageScanResult** and **ItemProcessor**) with the bounded generic type as:

```
@Builder
public class SegmentPageScanResult<TEntity extends ScannableEntity> {
  .
  .
  .
}
```

and

```
public class ItemProcessor<TEntity extends ScannableEntity> {

    void submitAndExecute(SegmentPageScanResult<TEntity> pageScanResult) {
          . . .
    }
}
```

When I am trying to initialize the SegmentPageScanResult and try calling `submitAndExecute` method of ItemProcessor from a Unit test as follows:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ScanTest {

    @Mock
    private ItemProcessor<Attachment> itemProcessor;

    @Test
    public void testDoScan() {
        Attachment mockRecord = new Attachment();
        SegmentPageScanResult<Attachment> segmentPageScanResult = SegmentPageScanResult.builder()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            .scannedItems(ImmutableList.of(mockRecord))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            .isLastPage(true)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            .build();  
            ^^^^^^^^^      
        verify(itemProcessor).submitAndExecute(segmentPageScanResult);

    }
}
```

I get the error -

```
Required type: SegmentPageScanResult<Attachment>
Provided:SegmentPageScanResult<ScannableEntity>
```

Can someone please help me understand why I am not able to initialize the generic object with the class implementing the interface?

Comment: show your verify(itemProcess) method signature...

Comment: Why did you expect this to work in the first place? Did you mean to write `SegmentPageScanResult<Attachment> segmentPageScanResult = SegmentPageScanResult.builder();` instead?

Comment: A class can't extend an interface. It can only implement it

Comment: @Sweeper I tried with SegmentPageScanResult<Attachment> as well, but then the same error was coming in the builder like ```Required type: SegmentPageScanResult<Attachment>
Provided: SegmentPageScanResult<ScannableEntity>```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of that.

Comment: @Sweeper I updated the the question above with more details.

Comment: @JCompetence verify() is a standard method of the Mockito framework. Its signature is not relevant here

Comment: @ChristophS. There is no class here extending an interface. `<TEntity extends ScannableEntity>` is a valid expression of a type parameter.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster Sorry, my fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have done:

```
ItemProcessor<Attachment> itemProcessor = new ItemProcessor<>();
```

And you also have:

```
SegmentPageScanResult<ScannableEntity> segmentPageScanResult = ...
```

So when you call:

```
itemProcessor.submitAndExecute(segmentPageScanResult, TEST_SEGMENT_ID, TEST_SCAN_ID);
```

There is a mismatch between the type of the itemProcessor (Attachment) and SegmentPageScanResult (ScannableEntity). So you probably need to create the ItemProcessor and the SegmentPageScanResult with the same type parameter.

EDIT: It's not completely clear what you are trying to achieve but maybe this can help:

```
public class ItemProcessor<T extends ScannableEntity> {

    private List<T> items;

    void submitAndExecute(SegmentPageScanResult pageScanResult) {
        pageScanResult.setScannedItems(items);
    }
}

public class SegmentPageScanResult {

    private final List<ScannableEntity> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setScannedItems(List<? extends ScannableEntity> items) {
        this.items.addAll(items);
    }
}
```

So the SegmentPageScanResult no longer has a type parameter because it only handles ScannableEntity instances. To allow setting different types from each ItemProcessor, the method parameter allows subtypes with `List<? extends ScannableEntity>`

Comment: You are right, when I change it to `ItemProcessor< ScannableEntity>` it works. But I need to create the instances of the classes, like `Attachment` and not the interface like `ScannableEntity`.

Comment: Thanks for the edited response! Actually replacing the `SegmentPageScanResult .builder()` with `new SegmentPageScanResult()` along with your original answer fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

basically the answer is simple:  here you specified that a class of type ScannableEntity will come. but you used SegmentPageScanResult, You used the ScannableEntity interface itself, I think that if you use the Attachment class that implements the interface class, not the interface class, the problem will be fixed, for example: You can use it as SegmentPageScanResult.